# Facebook post using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to post some text and pictures on facebook with a little Java program.

I am not able to post anything since I cannot click the appropriate button with selenium.

Here is the part of code where I need to click the upload Photo/video button on:

```
package good;
    
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class HareKrishna {
    public static void main (String []args ) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/gt8201/AjaySingh/Automation Tools /chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver_linux64(1)/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("abc");
        driver.navigate().forward();
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("abx");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Alert  alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.navigate().forward();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Actions Act = new Actions(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mount_0_0_08\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"));
        Act.click().sendKeys("Hare krishna");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is click on this xpath `//*[@class="sjgh65i0"]//descendant::div[@class="m9osqain a5q79mjw gy2v8mqq jm1wdb64 k4urcfbm qv66sw1b"]` and it do to appear the pop-up "create publication".
Now you could add a comment with xpath `//*[@method="POST"]//descendant::*[@role="presentation"]//descendant::*[@role="textbox"]` or push button "add videos/photos"  `//*[@method="POST"]//descendant::div[@class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t buofh1pr tgvbjcpo"]//descendant::*[@role="button"]`

Later you could push button publish `//*[@method="POST"]//descendant::div[@class="k4urcfbm discj3wi dati1w0a hv4rvrfc i1fnvgqd j83agx80 rq0escxv bp9cbjyn"]//descendant::*[@role="button"]`